# Editing php / mysql table but does not update table

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I am trying to edit a mysql table, however when i submit the form, the table does not get updated, and the previous value remains the same. I am not getting any errors at all either...

i have tried running the update query directly in the database, and it works...can someone have a look at my code and see if they can help?

below is my code:

edit.php

```
<?php include('server.php') ?> 
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{    
    $responseid = $_POST['responseid'];

    $response=$_POST['response'];  


{    

        //updating the table
        $result = $conn->prepare ("UPDATE response SET response= '$response' WHERE responseid=$responseid");


        header("Location: results.php");
    }
}
?>
<?php
//getting id from url
$responseid = $_GET['id'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM response WHERE responseid=$responseid");


while ($response = $result->fetch())
{ 
    $response = $res['response'];
    $student_id = $res['student_id'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Edit Data</title>
</head>

<body>


    <form name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>response</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='date' value="<?php echo $response;?>"</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

results.php

```
<div id="table1" class="table1">    
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$searchTerm=$_POST['search']; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare(" SELECT question.description AS question, answer.description AS answer, discipline.name AS name, response.responseid AS responseid, response.response AS response, response.student_id AS student_id, response.Date_Time AS Date
        FROM response
        INNER JOIN answer ON response.question_id = answer.answerid
        INNER JOIN question ON response.question_id = question.qid
        INNER JOIN discipline ON response.discipline_id = discipline.disciplineid WHERE Date_Time LIKE :searchTerm");
$stmt->bindValue(':searchTerm','%'.$searchTerm.'%');
$stmt->execute();
$result=0;




    /*
The above code is a query which selects attributes according to the search term
*/



echo "<table> <tr><th>Discipline</th><th>Question</th><th>Student ID</th><th>Response</th><th>Date & Time</th><th>Answer</th><th>Final Marks</th></tr>";
while ($response = $stmt->fetch())    /* This is a While loop which iterates each row */
{

echo " <tr><td>".$response["name"]."</td><td>".$response["question"]."</td><td>".$response["student_id"]."</td><td>".$response["response"]."</td><td>".$response["Date"]."</td><td><input type='text' name='date' value=". $response["answer"]."></td><td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$response[responseid]\">Edit</a></td></tr> "; 
    $result++;


}



}  /* This bit of code closes the connection with the database */
?>


    </div>
```

[please click this link to see my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYmad.png)

Comment: Seems  you don't know how prepare does work.. take a look at the docs again

Comment: @B001 where is the error in my prepared statement?

Comment: @b001 if I could find it I wouldn't be asking on here

Comment: you never executed anything in the edit.php file, you only prepared and is an easy fix.

Comment: @Funk Forty Miner can you please tell me how to fix it as I'm new to php and I'm unsure on how to go about it

Comment: change both `prepare` to `query` in the edit.php file and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I have just tried it but it's still the same.....

Comment: Good - you at least know about prepared statements (although you don't execute it) - bad is that you miss the point of prepared statements and insert the text directly into the statement rather than binding the values.

Comment: you have answers; one of them basically outlines what I told you to do, but they obviously didn't read the comments here.

Comment: @funk forty Niner thank you. I have got it working

Comment: welcome and how did you go about it exactly?

Comment: @Funk forty Niner I basically used Nigel Rens answer, copied it word for word and it worked straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating using prepared statements (similar to the way your doing it in the select in the second listing)...

```
//updating the table
$result = $conn->prepare ("UPDATE response 
                            SET response= :response 
                            WHERE responseid=:responseid");
$result->bindValue(':response',$response);
$result->bindValue(':responseid', $responseid);
$result->execute();
```

Also check the contents of `$_POST` as I think you have the field names wrong (think they were 'date' and 'id')...

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
    <table border="0">
        <tr> 
            <td>response</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='response' value="<?php echo $response;?>"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="responseid" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```